# How can I know the time the desktop has shown?

Tags: windows

I just want to run an application after the user has unlocked the PC.  Since the system can run applications automatically as specified in the registry after the user has logon, I think there must be a time point when I can run a application.

I have tried to run the application when the user unlock the PC, but it's too early, I must run it after the desktop has displayed.

Is there a system event (callback) or something else I can use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer. The system will set the event "WinSta0_DesktopSwitch" when user unlocks

Comment: But I think this is not the best solution。

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using "task scheduler"?

There are a few triggers including "workstation unlock" event.

I believe many enterprises also using the same way.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but the task scheduler is not a very good option for me.    By the way, I didn't know a task can begin when the workstation unlock or lock, so thank you for letting me learn something new.